# Probability Review Math Question

Tags: probability

I am currently stuck on the following probability problem:

“If 7 boys and 4 girls line up in the cafeteria in a random order, find the probability that the people at the beginning and at the end of the line are the same sex?”

In the textbook, it states that the answer is 27/55 but I am unsure how to reach that answer.

Comment: Please do not remove your question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

There are $11!$ of all possibilities how to line them all up. Then there are $2\binom{7}{2}$ ways to choose two boys at the beginning and end of the line (order matters, so times $2$), and rest can be permuted in $9!$ ways. Similarly there are $2\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two girls at the beginning and end of the line, and rest is again $9!$ permutations. So overall
$$
\frac{2\binom{7}{2}9!+2\binom{4}{2}9!}{11!}=\frac{27}{55}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The event that the front and last are the same gender is equivalent to the front and last both being boys or the front and last both being girls.

The first being a boy occurs with probability $\frac{7}{11}$ and the last being a boy *given that the first* is a boy will be $\frac{6}{10}$.  The probability then that both of these occur, the first and last both being boys will be the product of these, $\frac{7}{11}\times\frac{6}{10}$.

Similarly, the first being a girl occurs with probability $\frac{4}{11}$ and the last a girl given that the first is a girl will be $\frac{3}{10}$

The probability of either will then be:

$$\frac{7}{11}\times\frac{6}{10}+\frac{4}{11}\times\frac{3}{10} = \frac{27}{55}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in outcome of 2 places you can take probailities of just them. So probability of first and last person both being boys is 7/11 * 6/10= 42/110, and probability of both of them being girls are 4/11 * 3/10= 12/110
Adding these up we get 54/110 or 27/55